# Subject instantiation error in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

I have an Angular application that works fine via the `ng serve`. The application also builds correctly via `ng build --prod`, but when I run the generated sources in the browser I get a following error:

```
TypeError: $m.Subject is not a constructor
    at new e (error-handling.service.ts:8)
    at core.js:21140
    at Rs (core.js:21136)
    at Os (core.js:21075)
    at Gs.get (core.js:21628)
    at pu (core.js:21997)
    at du (core.js:21876)
    at su (core.js:21753)
    at Xd (core.js:30266)
    at Yd (core.js:30175)
    at Object.dh [as createRootView] (core.js:30688)
    at Ns.create (core.js:21357)
    at io.create (core.js:19158)
    at e.bootstrap (core.js:28031)
    at core.js:27742
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e._moduleDoBootstrap (core.js:27742)
    at core.js:27712
    at l.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27149)
    at l.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at i.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
    at zone-evergreen.js:857
    at l.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27137)
    at l.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at i.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at m (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

The `error-handling.service.ts` looks like below:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ErrorHandlingService {
  private errors: Subject<string[]> = new Subject(); // <-- error in this line

  constructor() {}

  public addErrors = (errors: string[]): void => this.errors.next(errors);

  public getErrors = () => this.errors.asObservable();
}
```

The code worked fine on Angular 9 after I've upgraded the project to 10 (which also upgraded TypeScript) it has stopped working.
It's a bit confusing why it works via `ng serve` and crashes when I run in production. Also, why this error is not caught during compilation?

Ivy is disabled for my project.

Comment: `Subject<string[]> = new Subject<string[]>();` could you try with this ?

Comment: is this correct? `import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";` ?  I usually see it come directly from `rxjs`, like this: `import { Subject } from "rxjs";`

Comment: @micronyks - no change

Comment: @BizzyBob - import from `rxjs` is blacklisted and linters complain about it. My code worked fine in previous Angular versions, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is definitely your import. `Subject` needs to be imported from `rxjs`.

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
```

There was an entire `rxjs-compat` module, even which would allow something like this. I'm pretty sure all this backwards compatibility supports has been dropped. This basically came from rxjs v5. I'm guessing you are somehow using rxjs v7 now, and they are definitely dropping it there.

You can read more about this [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#import-paths). You can see that `Subject` needs to be imported from `rxjs` directly. If your linters are complaining, these rules really need to be updated, because rxjs v6 has been released more than 2 years ago

Comment: Seems that you're right. I'm actually surprised as I was thinking that import from `rxjs` is bad as it imports everything while `rxjs/Subject` only subset which produces smaller bundles.

Comment: I am getting similar error but in Production build only. I have imported in same way but sill getting error. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AmbujKhanna did you find any solution?

Comment: @girish Yes. In my case there was issue with 3rd party library.